# Why is my mobile-friendly media screen query not working on my phone?

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, screen

I am using the following code in my main.css file for this particular query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav li {
    display: block;
    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
main p {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
img {
    border: 0.5px 0.5px solid #000;
}
#brands img {
    width: 75%;
}
footer {
    font-size: 20px;
}
}
```

Strangely, however, when I view my website on my phone, whose width is 360px, the the query does not show up as it does when I resize my Chrome window on my laptop.

[image: Viewing via resized Chrome window on laptop.]
[image: Viewing via my mobile Chrome tab on phone.]
I just asked my brother and he tells me that there's something else I'm supposed to use for mobile versions ... So, what am I missing here?

Comment: If you just saved the CSS file, it's possible that it didn't load it properly. You can try typing `javascript:reload(true)` in the browser bar on your phone, or connect it to a laptop and debug it with the Chrome debugger.

Comment: Or desktop, I suppose.

Comment: What to you have in your `<head></head>` ? Add: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` if you dont already have it.

Comment: Thank you, @RickSibley! That meta name viewport was precisely what I was missing. I remember it now that we used that for mobile optimization in my Web Design course at Fanshawe! (Darn, though! If only I could mark yours as the answer now.)

Comment: Anytime! It's all good, i'm happy to help solve the issue. Enjoy your day

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using on the phone? If it is an outdated browser it will not apply the media query because of the word **only** before screen.

Comment: Oh yes! I had meant to add that the word 'only' was added in see if it would fix this issue. My browser is Chrome 69.0.3497.100. Even after removing 'only', it remains the same, though.